# Angular&Rxjs :How to convert the returned observable object to json

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

[post method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siDN4.png)

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5j6gl.png)

I tried to convert the tokens through `JSON.parse'' and` JSON.stringify'', but I couldn't get the desired result.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call `JSON.parse(tokens.body);` after you checked that tokens contains data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but even though the value in the body has been changed to json format, an error will still be reported when doing storage operations.As a newbie, I feel very troubled

Comment: Thank you very much, I have solved it, "tokens.headers.get("Authorization") "needs to use json.stringify() to convert the object into a string when storing into localStorage